# I need to show formatted output as it shown below

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.forEach(caseChangeRecord, function(change, key) {
    if (caseChangeRecord != 'undefined') {
         body += change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue;
    }
});
```

Actual Display Output:

```
A:BA:A:BA:B
```

Need to display Output:

```
A:B

A:B

A:B
```

Comment: append a newline character `body += change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue+'\n';`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i tried your suggestion but its not working for me....

Comment: How/where are you using the `body` variable?

Comment: 'return {
 objectType: Constants.TYPE_INFO,
 objectIcon: 'fa-plus',
 objectBody: body };'

Comment: can you create a minimal plunker or jsfiddle. Its too hard to understand what you are really trying to do

Answer (score 0):

> body += change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue + ' < br>';

Comment: I tried your solution but its append &lt br &gt as it is.
like A:B&lt br &gtA:B&lt br &gtA:B

Comment: @MaheshSandhanshiv try the edited one.... if it doesn't works then try adding backslash ' \ ' ahead of greater than and less than sign

Comment: i tried </br> and \n solution but this solution also not working for me.

Comment: have you tried adding backslash ' \ ' ahead of greater than and less than sign? like ' \< '  and '\>'

Comment: body += change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue + '\<br\>' ;
For above line its print <br> tag in output

body += change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue + '\<'br'\>' ;
For above line its throwing unexpected error.

Answer (score 0):

`if (caseChangeRecord != 'undefined')` condition within your loop has no affect, since if `caseChangeRecord` is undefined, we will never enter the loop, in my example I assume that `caseChangeRecord` is an array (if it is an object, we can use `Object.keys(caseChangeRecord)` and get each item by its key).

Also, you probably need to use [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service and its `trustAsHtml()` function:

```
var caseChangeRecord = [
  {
    fieldName: 'A1',
    newValue: 'B1'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'A2',
    newValue: 'B2'
  },
  {
    fieldName: 'A3',
    newValue: 'B3'
  } 
];

if (caseChangeRecord) {
  $scope.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(caseChangeRecord.map(function (change) {
    return '<p>' + change.fieldName + ' : ' + change.newValue + '</p>';
  }).join(''));
}
```

then in your HTML you can use it like:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-bind-html="body"></body>
```

it is not exactly your case, but I think this way you can solve your issue, if you need an exact solution for your case, update my plunker and I will try to help.

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mk1Fbguce7ctXlVN6qsf?p=preview